# Testacular Angular UI bootstrap 'directive' is required

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, karma-runner

I'm trying to unit test a controller which uses the Angular UI-Bootstrap dialog directive, but am receiving a **Error: Argument 'directive' is required** error.

This actually occurs as soon as I include the `ui-bootstrap.min.js` file in the Testacular config.

The controller is defined as:

```
angular.module('xFormsEntries')
    .controller('xFormsEntryListCtrl', function ($scope, $dialog, Form, FormEntry, FormField) {...
```

The unit test is:

```
describe('xForms Controllers', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        this.addMatchers({
            toEqualData: function(expected) {
                return angular.equals(this.actual, expected);
            }
        });
    });

    beforeEach(module('xFormsServices'));
    beforeEach(module('xFormsEntries'));

    describe('xFormsEntryListCtrl', function() {
        var scope, ctrl, $httpBackend, $dialog;
        var formData = {formId: 1, name: 'FormName'};

        apiURL = ''; // Override the global API URL

        beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller, _$dialog_) {
            // Arrange
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            $httpBackend.expectGET('/xFormsAPI/Form').respond(formData);

            $dialog = _$dialog_;

            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            scope.formId = 1;
            ctrl = $controller('xFormsEntryListCtrl', {$scope: scope});
        }));

        it('should fetch the form from the server', function () {
            expect(scope.formModel).toBe(undefined);
            $httpBackend.flush();
            expect(scope.formModel).toEqualData(formData);
        });
});
```

All tests were passing before integrating UI-Bootstrap.

I've tried adding `beforeEach(module('ui.bootstrap'));`, and other variations, into the test with no luck.

What magic include am I missing to make this work?

Comment: What does your main module declaration look like?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the dependency as well as the actual js file?

Installation
As soon as you've got all the files downloaded and included in your page you just need to declare a dependency on the ui.bootstrap module:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```